# How to recover a specific user password in jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, windows-server-2008, jenkins-pipeline

I m new with jenkins and i want to  know if it s possible to recover jenkins password for a specific user or reinitialis it?

i found a hashed password of the user in **config.xml** file but i don t know if it s possible to decrypt it

i m using **windows server  and jenkins is deployed in my tomcat server**

thnks

Comment: i'm not certain this is the case with jenkins, but typically passwords are one-way hashes, and you therefore can't take the hashed value, decrypt it, and get back the plain text password.

Comment: Passwords in Jenkins are not hashes! They are actually encrypted. Therefore, they are decryptable using the secret.

Comment: i have +1'd your answer since it sounds like you know what you're talking about. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a hashed password but an encrypted one. Jenkins stores the secrets on its master node.

You could enter the **Groovy console** in Jenkins (accessible via **/script** added to your root URL) and try the following:

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("<EXTRACTED_CIPHERTEXT_FROM CONFIG.XML"))
```

**Explanation**

Using the decrypt directly within Jenkins will give the method trusted access to the secret, so it should be possible to decrypt it.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: thnk u the problem is that i can t authentify to use the script . is there any enlign tools that could help to  decrypt the password